# Rotation to obtain coordinate in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I trying to implement the below answer by Yves Daoust.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065013/rotation-to-obtain-corodinate

**Code**

```
to-report calx2 [x0 y0 x1 y1 A]
  report x0 + (y1 - y0) * tan ( A + atan (y1 - y0) (x1 - x0))
end
```

I don't seem to get intended output(can't figure the mistake from o/p testing). Where am going wrong? It seems I have some problem in how to implementing atan in NetLogo considering the axes are according to turtle.

Please point the error if possible. 
Also, are there any easier ways to accomplish the same in NetLogo.

Comment: Can you give one or more examples of inputs on which you get a wrong answer, and specify what wrong answer you get, and what the correct answer is that you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the mistake it should atan x y. As I was inverse it two times as the answered question already considered the angle A with vertical axis ,that is, NetLogo's axis style.